# Internet explorer and mozilla rgba css3 problem

Tags: css, rgba

I have this css style:

```
    background:#000;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    background: transparent;
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000,endColorstr=#B2000000)"; /* IE8 */    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000,endColorstr=#B2000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
    zoom: 1;
```

It works great in internet explorer, but i have to keep the  background: transparent; style. **If i keep it, mozilla makes my background transparent**

Any ideeas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learn to deal with IE quirks using IE Conditionals:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

```
<style type="text/css">
.stuff {
  background:#000;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.stuff {
  background: transparent;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000,endColorstr=#B2000000)"; /* IE8 */    
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000,endColorstr=#B2000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */
  zoom: 1;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<div class="stuff">Stuff</div>
```

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cYtKJ/1/

**EDIT**

You could also use it to import different style files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style-ie.css">
<![endif]-->
```

You just have to be careful to put the style-ie.css last if it's overriding other css commands.

Comment: Well, what you probably want to do is code up your style.css just as normal, and then create a style-ie.css and do a separate call to import it using the conditional. See my edit.

Comment: And no, you don't want conditionals inside your .css (or .js) files, since they are HTML and will break those files.

Answer (score 0):

```
    background: transparent;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000,endColorstr=#B2000000)"; /* IE8 */    
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#B2000000,endColorstr=#B2000000);   /* IE6 & 7 */      
    zoom: 1;
```

Problem solved.
However, there might be issues in IE9, since it supports RGBA too. 
So probably the best solution is to use conditional comments or just a solid color fallback in non-RGBA browsers.